# X-Editable and SQL Injection

Tags: mysql, .net, sql-injection

I am using jQuery in conjunction with X Editable in a web project. The backend file that edits the database table basically builds an SQL string with the cell name and value to be updated, as such:

```
string mysqlstring = "UPDATE SOMETABLE SET " + field + " = '" + value + "';";
```

I'm not an SQL expert, but it does not feel good from an SQL Injection perspective. I would much rather prefer a procedure where I can set the table name (if possible), field name and the value using Parameters somehow. Does anyone know how to do this?

Using .Net, and database is MySql.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are good ways to prevent SQL injection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: Thanks, but only answers part of the question. Can I also send in the table name and cell name as parameters? Not only the value?